# How to specify the target_os in `Cargo.toml`?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'm trying to write a crate that only works on `linux`. I have done some searches but all answers are just talking about:

1. add `#[cfg(target_os = xxx)]` in the source code
2. add `[target.'cfg(target_os = "linux")'.dependencies]` in
   `Cargo.toml.`

But in my case, the crate **entirely won't work** in other platform so I don't want to add `#[cfg]` in my code. If I do so, I need to add it to every piece of my code.

Is there a easy way to make my code only compile in specific platform?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can conditionally include an invocation of [`compile_error`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.compile_error.html):

```rust
#[cfg(not(target_os = "linux"))]
compile_error!("only linux is supported");
```

This only needs to appear in your code once; I'd suggest somewhere near the start of the root module.